# Django ignore mysql connection error

Tags: python, mysql, django

How do I "ignore" or "pass" on an MySQL connection error using Django?

Right now when my app tries to connect to the Database and the Database is offline (for whatever reason (update etc)) the script just throws the error but I want the script to continue running even if there is no database connection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

What about using `try`/`except`?

```py
try:
    # connect to the DB
except MySQLConnectionError:
    pass
# continue script
```

Comment: I do not connect to the database myself. Django is doing so. I put the credentials in the settings file and django connects itself.

Comment: I see. In that case I'd figure out which lines in the script depend on that connection and would throw that error on execution,  and wrap those in try/excepts. If it's all controlled by a higher-level config, I'll defer to someone with a bit more experience in Django than myself.

Comment: Thats already done. But Django is throwing the error not my script. I cant/dont want to change the django source code.